# Drag & Drop from 2 Sources to 1 Target in Flex, is it possible?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

My question is simple. Let's say I have 2 `List Controls`. 1 of Users and 1 of Tickets. (The 2 Sources)

And I have a `DataGrid` (the target). Is possible to select 1 user and 1 ticket in the 2 list mentioned before and drag & drop them at the same time to the `DataGrid`?

I know it's not as simple as they are going to get automatically mixed.. If it is possible... I would have to use the  `DragEnter` Event of the `Datagrid` or something to mix them and create my dataProvider. But I don't know how you can drag & drop 2 items at the same time from different sources. It is possible with one source.. But no idea of how to do it with 2 sources.

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1 mouse 2 items. I cant even visualize it. I think you need to rethink what you are doing. Go outside find 2 trees next to each other. Now push on them. good. Now use one hand. how can your hand be on 2 trees at the same time?

Comment: Yah I don't think this would be a very clear interaction but I could see kind of what you're saying.  I think it would be clearer to just have a button you press after selecting the items from the two lists that then creates an entry in the datagrids dataprovider.

Comment: I have it like that, with a button, but I was looking if it was possible to do it ...in fact I have 2 selected items in 2 list... I think some way is possible, something with the DragManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think that would still be possible.

Your option would be:

(click) select the item on the Users and click (select) the item on the Tickets.

From whichever list you started the drag, you would still be able to populate the datagrid with the items from dragEvent and the selected item on the list.

```
// 
boolUsers:Boolean;

On your datagrid:
private function dataGrid_dragDrop(evt:DragEvent) :void
{
  // This will get the items from the list where you initiated the drag.
  var objDrag:Object;
  objDrag = evt.dragSource.dataForFormat("items");


  // Depending on where the drag was initiated, get the items from the list.
  var objList:Object;
  if(boolUsers)
  {
    objList = listTickets.selectedItem;
  }
  else
  {
    objList = listUsers.selectedItem;
  }

  boolUsers = false;
}
```

And you would need to define a dragstart event for both your list

```
private function listUsers_dragStart(evt:DragEvent) :void
{
  boolUsers = true;
}
```